# Is a single argument constructor with a default value the same as a default constructor?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, default-constructor, c++98, default-arguments

Specifically in the context of automatic calling of the base class constructor: Is a single argument constructor of a base class with a default value handled the same way (e.g. automatically called if not specified otherwise) as a default constructor (a constructor without arguments)?

```cpp
struct base {
  base(int value = 42) {}
};
struct derived : public base {
  derived() {} // automatic call to base::base(int) ?
};
```

---

*edit: The following does NOT relate to the question, it's just how I came upon this. The following code even does not exhibit the crash I've been seeing. See below for an actual example.*

Consider this:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
// C++98, std::ostringstream(ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out) available
struct OhNo : public std::ostringstream {
  OhNo() {
  }
  void Crash() const {
    this->str();
  }
};
// later: OhNo f; f.Crash();
```

`std::ostringstream` (prior to C++11) [didn't have a no-argument constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/basic_ostringstream). Just one with a single argument and a default value.  <s>The above `OhNo` does not call the constructor of it's base class.</s> (**Yes it does**) AFAIK the base class constructor is automatically called *if* there's a no-argument constructor available.

GCC 5.4.0 compiles fine with this but later segfaults (due to <s>the uninitialized base class</s> *another issue*).
Clang 7.0.0 also compiles fine with this and also runs the code without issue.

Who's right? Is it necessary to manually call the base class constructor here? *Answer: No!*

Affected code: [UnitTest++ `MemoryOutStream` class](https://github.com/unittest-cpp/unittest-cpp/blob/master/UnitTest%2B%2B/MemoryOutStream.h)

Related issue: https://github.com/unittest-cpp/unittest-cpp/issues/174

---

**Ok, I've no idea what's going on. Disassembly of the below shows that the base constructor is called. So the answer is most probably "YES".** For anyone who's interested, here's how to reproduce this very strange behaviour:

```cpp
#include "UnitTest++.h"

volatile double A() { return 2; }

TEST(Crash) {
  CHECK_CLOSE(1,A(),0.1);
}

int main()
{
 int exit_code = 0;
 exit_code = UnitTest::RunAllTests();
 return exit_code;
}
```

Compile with g++ against libunittest++.a and it's headers (for example from https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libunittest++-dev/download).

Run it normally:

```
test.cc:5: error: Failure in Crash: Unhandled exception: Crash!
FAILURE: 1 out of 1 tests failed (1 failures).
Test time: 0.00 seconds.
```

Run it in gdb:

```
(gdb) catch throw
Catchpoint 1 (throw)
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/musteresel/huh/libunittest++-dev_1.4.0-3_amd64/data/usr/lib/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7f205a0 in std::string::assign(std::string const&) () from /nix/store/hlnxw4k6931bachvg5sv0cyaissimswb-gcc-7.4.0-lib/lib/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7f205a0 in std::string::assign(std::string const&) () from /nix/store/hlnxw4k6931bachvg5sv0cyaissimswb-gcc-7.4.0-lib/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x0000000000403a7a in UnitTest::MemoryOutStream::GetText() const ()
#2  0x0000000000402871 in UnitTest::CheckClose<int, double, double> (results=..., expected=@0x7fffffffbabc: 1, actual=@0x7fffffffbac0: 2, 
    tolerance=@0x7fffffffbac8: 0.10000000000000001, details=...) at ../include/unittest++/Checks.h:53
#3  0x0000000000402483 in TestCrash::RunImpl (this=0x408060 <testCrashInstance>) at test.cc:6
#4  0x0000000000402bc2 in void UnitTest::ExecuteTest<UnitTest::Test>(UnitTest::Test&, UnitTest::TestDetails const&) ()
#5  0x0000000000403255 in UnitTest::TestRunner::RunTest(UnitTest::TestResults*, UnitTest::Test*, int) const ()
#6  0x0000000000403683 in UnitTest::RunAllTests() ()
#7  0x0000000000402514 in main () at test.cc:14
(gdb)
```

Disassembly - **clearly** shows constructor is being called:

```
# in UnitTest::CheckClose<int, double, double>
  4027cb:       e8 e2 fd ff ff          callq  4025b2 <UnitTest::MemoryOutStream::MemoryOutStream()>

# in UnitTest::MemoryOutStream::MemoryOutStream()
  4025eb:       e8 60 fa ff ff          callq  402050 <std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream(std::_Ios_Openmode)@plt>
```

Comment: The premise is incorrect. The shown code will most certainly construct the base class. This is how C++ has always worked. If there is no constructor available, the code would be ill-formed and it wouldn't compile. Whatever's the reason for the crash, it is not due to this.

Comment: I can see the base class ctor [plainly on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/upMCqq), configured using gcc5.4 and C++98 language level. Are you saying your asm is *different* ?

Comment: @WhozCraig .. I'm currently re-running the test as much isolated as possible. No, on godbolt it looks the same to me (ofc)

Comment: @DanielJour No, i meant the asm view of your compiled code in  your environment where this seems to be failing. Ofc it will look the same to you on GB as it does to me.

Comment: Wait ... it's not GCC 5.4.0 ... that's what I'm compiling with ... but then I link against a static library (unittest++) .. I have no idea with what that library had been compiled with.

Comment: @WhozCraig still fails, though apparently only in the context of unittest++ ... current travis build: https://travis-ci.com/musteresel/libopenshot/jobs/259727094#L1474 I'm trying to make a reproducible example just with unittest++ in there ...

Comment: A 1 parameter (defaulted) function acts like a 0 parameter function; that's the very idea of default arguments. So 1 default param ctor acts as a default ctor.

Comment: From the way you phrase your edit, it seems that you are not manually compiling `libunittest++.a` with the same compiler? You may simply have an ABI mismatch in the `std::string` type. For C++11 there was a breaking change, that the linker wouldn't notice if `std::string` is used as a data member, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From ISO/IEC 14882:1998(E) [class.ctor]/5

> A *default* constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument.

A default constructor may have parameters as long as they all have default arguments and, thus, the constructor can be called without arguments.

If you do not explicitly specify a *mem-initializer* for your base class in your constructor's initializer list, then the base class will be initialized via its default constructor.

`std::basic_ostringstream` had a default constructor already in C++98 (a constructor with one parameter which had a default argument). If you look closely, you'll find that cppreference page you linked confirms this…

Comment: "a default constructor already in C++98 (a constructor with one parameter which had a default argument)" ... that *this* is in fact a default constructor was the main question. But your quote answers this ... a constructor with one parameter which has a default arg **can** be called without an argument.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to address the motivation for the question before the question itself. The motivating example is

> `std::ostringstream` (prior to C++11) [didn't have a no-argument constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/basic_ostringstream). Just one with a single argument and a default value.

While true, this is not the change to focus on. Prior to C++11, there was a default constructor. Its signature was effectively (not literally)

```
explicit basic_ostringstream();
```

Starting with C++11, the signature became

```
basic_ostringstream();
```

Note the difference? The default constructor is no longer flagged `explicit`. This was the desired change. It was also desired that the constructor taking an `openmode` as its only parameter remain `explicit`. Hence, there was a need to increase the number of constructor declarations. (See also the defect report listed on the page to which you linked.)

> Is a single argument constructor with a default value the same as a default constructor?

Not really, since the former can be called with an argument. :P But for the question I believe you intended, yes, a constructor for which all arguments have default values does serve as the default constructor for that class.

> Who's right? Is it necessary to manually call the base class constructor here?

Crashing tends to mean you have undefined behavior. At least, I cannot recall any part of the standard that calls for crashing as the required behavior. :) When the behavior is undefined, there is no wrong behavior. (Everyone is right.)